# error installing freeipa-server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, freeipa

I am trying to install freeipa-server using the ipa-server-install command. When installing freeipa-server in debian from the experimental repository, an error occurs related to not_valid_after_it's not_valid_before_utc time. What causes it and how to fix it?
The following is the download steps that occurred and logs in which nothing was found that could help.

Download stages.

```
  [1/43]: creating directory server instance
Validate installation settings ...
Create file system structures ...
selinux is disabled, will not relabel ports or files.
Create database backend: dc=zxc,dc=ru ...
Perform post-installation tasks ...
  [2/43]: tune ldbm plugin
  [3/43]: adding default schema
  [4/43]: enabling memberof plugin
  [5/43]: enabling winsync plugin
  [6/43]: configure password logging
  [7/43]: configuring replication version plugin
  [8/43]: enabling IPA enrollment plugin
  [9/43]: configuring uniqueness plugin
  [10/43]: configuring uuid plugin
  [11/43]: configuring modrdn plugin
  [12/43]: configuring DNS plugin
  [13/43]: enabling entryUSN plugin
  [14/43]: configuring lockout plugin
  [15/43]: configuring graceperiod plugin
  [16/43]: configuring topology plugin
  [17/43]: creating indices
  [18/43]: enabling referential integrity plugin
  [19/43]: configuring certmap.conf
  [20/43]: configure new location for managed entries
  [21/43]: configure dirsrv ccache and keytab
  [22/43]: enabling SASL mapping fallback
  [23/43]: restarting directory server
  [24/43]: adding sasl mappings to the directory
  [25/43]: adding default layout
  [26/43]: adding delegation layout
  [27/43]: creating container for managed entries
  [28/43]: configuring user private groups
  [29/43]: configuring netgroups from hostgroups
  [30/43]: creating default Sudo bind user
  [31/43]: creating default Auto Member layout
  [32/43]: adding range check plugin
  [33/43]: creating default HBAC rule allow_all
  [34/43]: adding entries for topology management
  [35/43]: initializing group membership
  [36/43]: adding master entry
  [37/43]: initializing domain level
  [38/43]: configuring Posix uid/gid generation
  [39/43]: adding replication acis
  [40/43]: activating sidgen plugin
  [41/43]: activating extdom plugin
  [42/43]: configuring directory to start on boot
  [43/43]: restarting directory server
Done configuring directory server (dirsrv).
Configuring Kerberos KDC (krb5kdc)
  [1/11]: adding kerberos container to the directory
  [2/11]: configuring KDC
  [3/11]: initialize kerberos container
  [4/11]: adding default ACIs
  [5/11]: creating a keytab for the directory
  [6/11]: creating a keytab for the machine
  [7/11]: adding the password extension to the directory
  [8/11]: creating anonymous principal
  [9/11]: starting the KDC
  [10/11]: configuring KDC to start on boot
  [11/11]: enable PAC ticket signature support
Done configuring Kerberos KDC (krb5kdc).
Configuring kadmin
  [1/2]: starting kadmin 
  [2/2]: configuring kadmin to start on boot
Done configuring kadmin.
Configuring ipa-custodia
  [1/5]: Making sure custodia container exists
  [2/5]: Generating ipa-custodia config file
  [3/5]: Generating ipa-custodia keys
  [4/5]: starting ipa-custodia 
  [5/5]: configuring ipa-custodia to start on boot
Done configuring ipa-custodia.
Configuring certificate server (pki-tomcatd). Estimated time: 3 minutes
  [1/30]: configuring certificate server instance
  [2/30]: stopping certificate server instance to update CS.cfg
  [3/30]: backing up CS.cfg
  [4/30]: Add ipa-pki-wait-running
  [5/30]: secure AJP connector
  [6/30]: reindex attributes
  [7/30]: exporting Dogtag certificate store pin
  [8/30]: disabling nonces
  [9/30]: set up CRL publishing
  [10/30]: enable PKIX certificate path discovery and validation
  [11/30]: authorizing RA to modify profiles
  [12/30]: authorizing RA to manage lightweight CAs
  [13/30]: Ensure lightweight CAs container exists
  [14/30]: Ensuring backward compatibility
  [15/30]: starting certificate server instance
  [16/30]: configure certmonger for renewals
  [17/30]: requesting RA certificate from CA
  [error] TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class IPACertificate with abstract methods not_valid_after_utc, not_valid_before_utc
Can't instantiate abstract class IPACertificate with abstract methods not_valid_after_utc, not_valid_before_utc
The ipa-server-install command failed. See /var/log/ipaserver-install.log for more information
```

The log file

```
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG   [17/30]: requesting RA certificate from CA
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG Starting external process
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG args=['/usr/bin/openssl', 'pkcs7', '-inform', 'DER', '-print_certs', '-out', '/var/lib/ipa/tmpzohnbt8x']
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=0
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG stdout=
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG stderr=
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG Starting external process
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG args=['/usr/bin/openssl', 'pkcs12', '-nokeys', '-clcerts', '-in', '/root/ca-agent.p12', '-out', '/var/lib/ipa/tmp9lk304vz', '-passin', 'file:/tmp/tmp4z3cyt00']
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=0
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG stdout=
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG stderr=
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG Starting external process
2024-03-28T15:26:22Z DEBUG args=['/usr/bin/openssl', 'pkcs12', '-nocerts', '-in', '/root/ca-agent.p12', '-out', '/var/lib/ipa/tmpdmbxzx35', '-passin', 'file:/tmp/tmpqoy9bgxk', '-nodes']
2024-03-28T15:26:23Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=0
2024-03-28T15:26:23Z DEBUG stdout=
2024-03-28T15:26:23Z DEBUG stderr=
2024-03-28T15:26:31Z DEBUG certmonger request is in state 'GENERATING_KEY_PAIR'
2024-03-28T15:26:31Z DEBUG certmonger request is in state 'SUBMITTING'
2024-03-28T15:26:32Z DEBUG certmonger request is in state 'PRE_SAVE_CERT'
2024-03-28T15:26:33Z DEBUG certmonger request is in state 'POST_SAVED_CERT'
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG certmonger request is in state 'MONITORING'
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG Cert request 20240328152630 was successful
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG Starting external process
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG args=['/usr/sbin/selinuxenabled']
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=1
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG stdout=
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG stderr=
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG Starting external process
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG args=['/usr/sbin/selinuxenabled']
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=1
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG stdout=
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG stderr=
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/service.py", line 686, in start_creation
    run_step(full_msg, method)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/service.py", line 672, in run_step
    method()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/cainstance.py", line 936, in __request_ra_certificate
    self.ra_cert = x509.load_certificate_from_file(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipalib/x509.py", line 465, in load_certificate_from_file
    return load_pem_x509_certificate(f.read())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipalib/x509.py", line 427, in load_pem_x509_certificate
    return IPACertificate(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class IPACertificate with abstract methods not_valid_after_utc, not_valid_before_utc

2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG   [error] TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class IPACertificate with abstract methods not_valid_after_utc, not_valid_before_utc
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG Removing /root/.dogtag/pki-tomcat/ca
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/admintool.py", line 180, in execute
    return_value = self.run()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/cli.py", line 344, in run
    return cfgr.run()
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 360, in run
    return self.execute()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 386, in execute
    for rval in self._executor():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 435, in __runner
    exc_handler(exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 468, in _handle_execute_exception
    self._handle_exception(exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 458, in _handle_exception
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 425, in __runner
    step()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 419, in step_next
    return next(self.__gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/util.py", line 81, in run_generator_with_yield_from
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/util.py", line 59, in run_generator_with_yield_from
    value = gen.send(prev_value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 663, in _configure
    next(executor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 435, in __runner
    exc_handler(exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 468, in _handle_execute_exception
    self._handle_exception(exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 526, in _handle_exception
    self.__parent._handle_exception(exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 458, in _handle_exception
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 523, in _handle_exception
    super(ComponentBase, self)._handle_exception(exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 458, in _handle_exception
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 425, in __runner
    step()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 419, in step_next
    return next(self.__gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/util.py", line 81, in run_generator_with_yield_from
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/util.py", line 59, in run_generator_with_yield_from
    value = gen.send(prev_value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipapython/install/common.py", line 65, in _install
    for unused in self._installer(self.parent):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/server/__init__.py", line 566, in main
    master_install(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/server/install.py", line 278, in decorated
    func(installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/server/install.py", line 914, in install
    ca.install_step_0(False, None, options, custodia=custodia)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/ca.py", line 404, in install_step_0
    ca.configure_instance(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/cainstance.py", line 506, in configure_instance
    self.start_creation(runtime=runtime)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/service.py", line 686, in start_creation
    run_step(full_msg, method)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/service.py", line 672, in run_step
    method()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipaserver/install/cainstance.py", line 936, in __request_ra_certificate
    self.ra_cert = x509.load_certificate_from_file(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipalib/x509.py", line 465, in load_certificate_from_file
    return load_pem_x509_certificate(f.read())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipalib/x509.py", line 427, in load_pem_x509_certificate
    return IPACertificate(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2024-03-28T15:26:36Z DEBUG The ipa-server-install command failed, exception: TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class IPACertificate with abstract methods not_valid_after_utc, not_valid_before_utc
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z ERROR Can't instantiate abstract class IPACertificate with abstract methods not_valid_after_utc, not_valid_before_utc
2024-03-28T15:26:36Z ERROR The ipa-server-install command failed. See /var/log/ipaserver-install.log for more information
```

I tried to configure the ntp server in chrony, as well as change the time using tzdata and timedatectl set-timezone UTC. NTP installation is not possible because because of this, freeipa-server stops working and there is no ip-server-install command.